# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'regeneratorRuntime.mark')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, libraries, require, babel-preset-env

I'm having a trouble with this error for quite a while. I only did some renaming and copy and paste of some folders from my previous app to this app. **The app bundles to 100%.** but after that instead of opening my app it pops up this error message. If someone could help it would be amazing.[image]

this is my **package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"immutable": "^3.8.1",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.54.0",
"react-native-accordion": "^1.0.1",
"react-native-activity-indicator": "0.0.4",
"react-native-image-base64": "^0.1.2",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.19.3",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.3.0",
"react-native-material-switch": "0.0.4",
"react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.1",
"react-native-pages": "^0.7.0",
"react-native-rename": "^2.2.2",
"react-native-snackbar": "^0.4.1",
"react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
"react-native-switch": "^1.2.1",
"react-native-switch-pro": "^0.4.5",
"react-native-table-component": "^1.1.0",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
"react-redux": "^5.0.5",
"react-swipeable-views": "^0.12.13",
"redux": "^3.7.1",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-persist": "^4.9.1",
"redux-persist-transform-immutable": "^4.3.0",
"redux-saga": "^0.15.4",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
"reselect": "^3.0.1",
"rn-viewpager": "^1.2.9",
"validator": "^8.2.0"
```

},

```
     "devDependencies": {
       "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
       "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.0.0",
       "jest": "20.0.4",
       "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
     },
       "jest": {
       "preset": "react-native"
      }
}
```

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: Please add [mcve] to your question.

Comment: sorry, i had to put code or an example but this problem is not in my code ,but some library and version issues

Comment: You're probably calling some class / function that has gone out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guys I somehow managed to get it working, I removed the **caret(^)** symbol from the versions of all the packages mentioned in **package .json** and removed the node_modules and re-installed them.Thus i got it working